# Need to Create Ncover Report That does not Include private methods and properties in the Coverage

Tags: ncover

I an Creating Ncover report but in the report all the private methods and properties are also listed and they affect the coverage as well so is there any way to hide them.

thanks
priya

Comment: :better to add  test cases for that ( get set) properties and add more test cases for the public methods which calls the private method ( ensure that the private method is executed at least once during the test case execution,this is the way to improve the coverage

Comment: That's quite correct way but in my scenario I really don't require to Test some of the Properties and classes so Really need to Exclude Them from coverage.

Comment: :i have little knowledge in this scenario also  i submited a ticket in ncover regarding your issue, so if i got any reply from them i will inform you

Answer (score 1):

NCover cannot distinguish between *private methods, properties, and classes and other kinds of code*. So, the only way to exclude private methods is to create **pre-coverage filters** that exclude them specifically by name

The [help doc](http://www.ncover.com/support/docs/v4/feature-reference/desktop/pre_coverage_filter)  shows how to set up pre-coverage filters on the Settings tab of an NCover 4 project:

You will decide what to exclude based on your own knowledge of the source code, but a filter to exclude a method will look something like the example below:

"Exclude","Module","Matches","Algorithms.dll"

A filter to exclude a class will look something like the example below:
"Exclude","Class","Contains","SwapSorter"

Comment: Even the NCover support team can't answer about this issue, and they provided 2 links related to this http://www.ncover.com/support/docs/v3/ref/3-0/ncover-console/command-line/profiling-options#em  http://www.ncover.com/support/docs/v3/ref/3-0/ncover-console/command-line/profiling-options#et and gave an example to filter out some test methods, and some get/set methods:
//em ".*\.TestAddition;.*\.Addition;.*.get_.*"

Comment: i think in a big project this is impractical